# Sort by dynamic column

Tags: postgresql

I have an `items` table in PostgreSQL with 4 columns: start_price, end_price, start_date, duration.

I'd like to support queries to return items ordered by current_price, which is calculated by the formular as below

```
current_price = start_price + (end_price - start_price) * (current_time - start_date) / duration
```

How to design such table and the `current_price` column so that it's scalable and performant to support millions of rows?

Answer (score 1):

You could do that by defining a CTE.

E.g:

```
WITH c AS (
 SELECT
  start_price, 
  end_price, 
  start_date, 
  duration,
  start_price 
      + (end_price - start_price) * (current_time - start_date) 
      / duration AS current_price
FROM items
)
SELECT
  start_price, 
  end_price, 
  start_date, 
  duration,
  current_price
FROM c
ORDER BY current_price DESC;
```

You might wrap this query into a function or a view.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Is it scalable? Can it be still performant with millions of rows?

Comment: This query alone is light. But it depends of how you formulate joins, where's, order by or subqueries afterwards,